# How to avoid images getting downloaded locally with Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring 4 controller to display images from database and the images are loading properly in the HTML page in browser but when I copy the image `src` and paste it in the browser address bar the image does not open in the browser; instead a text file gets downloaded. How to resolve this issue?

> **Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageController/{imageId}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] helloWorld(@PathVariable int imageId,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception  { 
    FileInfo info=commonservice.getImg(imageId);
    byte[] imageInByte=null;
    if(info.getImageBytes() !=null){
        String ct=info.getContentType();
        String[]toks=ct.split("/");         
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(info.getImageBytes()));
        if(img !=null){
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write( img, toks[1], baos );
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        }
    }
  return imageInByte;
}
```

> **JSP file**

```
<img class="img-responsive"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/common/imageController/8.sjf" >
```

I have used browser's developer tools and found that the following response headers are returned by the server when accessing images:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=f.txt
Content-Length:19926
Content-Type:image/webp
Date:Tue, 10 May 2016 05:57:14 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=95
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The `Content-Disposition` header is set to "f.txt", which forces the browser to download the image as a file. How can I change this behaviour? I have already tried `response.setContentType()` and setting the `Content-Disposition` header myself but the image keeps getting downloaded as a file.

Comment: I have already tried with response.setContentType(). This is not working. even after setting this the direct links to images are downloading text files. I even have tried with setting the header "content-disposition" but did not work at all.

Comment: Ya i have updated my question with response headers. Please have a look. The site is live. you also can check this page http://sphoorthijyothifoundation.org/home/oc.sjf

Comment: Manish in the link i have provided if u scroll down there are so many images (the first image on top of the page can be downloaded so i am not talking about that). please try with them. I am not adding the content disposition. Spring automatically adds that to prevent RFD attacks. so i dont know how to remove it that is the reason i have posted in this forum.

Comment: For future reference, the `Content-Disposition` header is added automatically by Spring 4 due to the controller method `@ResponseBody public byte[] helloworld(...)`. More details are available in the [Spring JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13587). The fix is to change the controller method to `public void helloworld(HttpServletResponse response)` and writing the image data to the response directly.